# NetSuite Workflow lock PO record if related bill exists

Tags: netsuite

I have my custom purchasing workflow in place and it works as expected. It also has a feature to allow for resubmission of approved POs and there are no issues on that front so far. However, I am recently asked to  stop the users from modifying the PO if there is an associated bill for that PO.

I am trying to update the 'Lock Record' condition based on this but not sure what the condition should be. If someone can suggest this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be where "Document Status" = "Fully Billed".  I am not sure if there are instances in your enviornment where there would be a bill but the PO would not be "Fully Billed".  However, I do not see any PO Document Statuses that indicate "Partially Billed"...

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same requirement implemented in my account. You can implement the same thing. Attaching the screenshot of the workflow and action detail for your reference.Have this action run on "Before record load". I have excluded the admin from the lock hence admin would still have rights to make any changes.
Please let know how this goes!! :) Best of luck!

[image]